# What is meant by "con a con"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "con a con" and how could you use it in writing?
I would find examples useful.
**Note:** I encountered this phase from CSI TV show, when a crime scene investigator(CSI) took pity on a suspect. CSI said to a suspect that she really feel sorry for suspect's loss and she can help her(suspect) in all ways to recover from her loss. For that suspect told "you cannot con a con sweetie" to CSI.

Comment: A `con` refers to a convict. If you mean a confidence trickster, use `conman`

Comment: "Con", in this sense, is a verb, meaning to hoodwink.  "You can't con a con artist" is a common saying (where "con artist", obviously, is an expert at hoodwinking people).

Comment: Although Area 51 Detective Fiction's distinction (above) is generally a useful one, the particular phrase "Don't try to con a con" refers, as Hot Licks points out, to a "con[fidence] artist," no to a "con[vict]." It is analogous to such allied phrases as "Don't try to sharp a sharper" and "Don't try to bullshit a bullshitter." With regard to your question, it would help prospective answerers  to know what you have discovered on your own in researching the phrase and where you encountered it in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find different meanings of *con* in the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=con).

However, I think what you are looking for is used in a situation like this:

> You Can't Put No Boogie-Woogie on the King of Rock and Roll - You can't con a con artist. You can't baloney a baloneyist.

From *Eileen Ross - A Survivor's Story.*